# Can I override the HTC Sense "slide down to answer / slide up to decline" screen locker?

Tags: htc-sense, calls, htc-desire-hd

I can't be the only one who has this problem: my touchscreen reacts to the cotton of my jeans. I carry my DHD upside down in my pocket, and on an incoming call, when I drag it out of my pocket, it interacts with the jeans tissue and slides the bar up, thus declining the call.

I tried such apps as "Easy answer button," "Advanced telephone," "Full screen caller ID," but they simply overlap what's already on the screen, and while they do work (i.e., I press instead of swiping), either the result is very ugly, or the caller ID is partially invisible — not to mention I would like to swipe left/right (as in vanilla Android), rather than just press, as this is also not jeans-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom roms will be the only way to do this. [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&feature=search_result) changes the lock screen, but i don't think it handles incoming calls. This [Gingerbread rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=758197) changes the lock screen as well as how it answers calls, changing it to the Android swipe across system, but like all roms, it requires a root and a wipe. It is a great rom though, and will do exactly what you need.